# How to update only modified columns of a row in a table in SQL using Prepared Statement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sql-update

I have a table with say 4 columns of the following types.

```
uniqueID - VARCHAR(50) not NULL
firstName - VARCHAR(50) not NULL
lastName - VARCHAR(50) not NULL
score - INT not NULL
```

Now, I created a table called detailsTable using the below query:-

```
CREATE TABLE detailsTable (uniqueID VARCHAR(50) not NULL, firstName VARCHAR(50) not NULL, lastName VARCHAR(50) not NULL, score - INT not NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (uniqueID))
```

To insert data into the table, I used the prepared statement as shown below:-

```
StringBuilder insertQuery =  INSERT IGNORE INTO detailsTable(uniqueID ,firstName, lastName, score) VALUES (?,?,?,?)

PreparedStatement pstmnt= connection
                    .prepareStatement(insertQuery.toString(), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

pstmnt.setString(1,1);
pstmnt.setString(2,"Max");
pstmnt.setString(3,"Robin");
pstmnt.setString(4,"85");

pstmnt.execute();
```

Note that I used the JDBC connection to prepareStatement.

Suppose, the last name and score are to be modified. My requirement is to use the prepared statement itself to update the table. Also, only columns whose values are modified are to be updated. In the example, last name and score alone.

I created an update Query as below:-

```
 StringBuilder updateQuery = UPDATE detailsTable SET uniqueID=?,firstName =?,lastName=?,score=? WHERE uniqueID=1

PreparedStatement pstmnt= connection
                        .prepareStatement(updateQuery.toString(), Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
    
    pstmnt.setString(1,1);
    pstmnt.setString(2,"Max");
    pstmnt.setString(3,"Kevin");
    pstmnt.setString(4,"77");
```

Now, If I create a prepared statement using the above query and call executeUpdate(), It will update each column. But, I am looking for an efficient way, wherein only modified cells are updated.

Kindly note that the example is just intended to explain the scenario. My actual table has a large number of columns. So, I need to write a prepared statement that sets every details but only updates modified values. The input data that I receive contains complete information which makes it difficult to identify specific columns that need to be updated. Also, updates can happen to any of the columns and may not always be the same.

For this, how should I modify the update query? Is there an option that SQL PreparedStatement provides as inbuilt? Is there a better way to achieve the objective ?

(Please forgive me for being naive; I am new to SQL and that might be the reason for my difficulty in wrapping around the concepts and way of working)

Comment: *I am looking for an efficient way, wherein only modified cells are updated.* There is no difference between some and all columns update - anycase this causes one data block rewriting in on-disk table body file.

Comment: If you want to update only changed columns nevertheless then create 15 separate queries texts and prepare/execute only those which matches the columnset to be updated with according if/case.

Comment: @Akina - I just came across an example which states UPDATE detailsTable SET uniqueID=?,firstName =?,lastName=?,score=? WHERE uniqueID=1 AND not ( firstName  <=> lastName_new_value AND score <=> score_new_value )

Does this statement replace only modified cells?

Comment: You do not understand low-level of the UPDATE. The row to be updated is stored in memory. The column value updation in memory cache is very-very fast. Then, if at least one byte changes, the whole block (which contains this altered row and in general some adjacent rows) is written to disk which is slow while comparing with in-memory values change. So there is no difference does one or more columns is changed. Exclusion - TEXT/BLOB and long VARCHAR columns which are stored in separate place out of the row and, hence, whose change produces 2 separate writes (into table body and strings storage).